# How to combine a List with multple Dataframes in a single in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, for-loop

i have the next problem...
I have a list with the first element, a data frame with two variables (Product and Type), to be stored in a list "test" at position 1.

```
test[[1]]<-data.frame(Product = "Cheese", 
                  Type ="variable")
```

Automatically is stored as a dataframe within the list
[[1]] list1x2 and i need to insert a lot of data with a for loop (but this is my little example), but I have a problem when i insert more dataframes to the same list, like this...

```
test[[1]]<- append(test[[1]], data.frame(Product = paste("Cheese","1Kg"),
                                    Type = "variation"))
```

is not a list with two dataframes :/

im trying to use

```
d_combinated<-do.call(rbind, test)
```

and

```
data.table::rbindlist(test)
```

and..

```
d_combinated<- dplyr::bind_rows(test, .id = "variable")
```

but i get...

| Product | Type | Product | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cheese | variable | Cheese 1K | variation |

I need the next output...

| Product | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Cheese | variable |
| Cheese 1K | variation |

Please, any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `test[[1]] <- rbind(test[[1]], data.frame(Product = paste("Cheese","1Kg"),Type = "variation"))`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I spent my whole day trying to figure it out But append was not a good option